# Not able to add continuous border in breadcrum navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify breadcrum navigation styling as given here
http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

I wanted borders around the li's but when i put the border it is not
continuous.I have added image and fiddle of the same

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/K7ChN/

Right now just the li has the border

```
.breadcrumb li {
    border : 2px solid #8ebed1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that, since the triangles are added in CSS. This triangles are made by setting the aproppiate border...

maybe with a background-image?